# showing php jsonencode array result into ajax success function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to show result of my php code to ajax file with jquery but I don't know how to do it. Final array `[{"UPDATE_TIME":"2016-11-28 06:51:51"}]`

I want to show this result through ajax jquery.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

include_once "dbconfig.php";

$sql = "SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'vizteyl7_tarining'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'news'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $output[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($output);
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

```
 <label>Enter TimeStamp (last updated date: <span id="lastTs"></span>)</label>
```

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
              setTs();
      })

  function setTs(){

  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"http://example.com/stshow.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#lastTs').text(data[0]);

}
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$('#lastTs').text(data[0].UPDATE_TIME);
```

Comment: error showing for $(document).ready(function(){
              setTs();
      })
its saying $ is not defined but nothing showing for main ajax,its showing blank screen,no output

Comment: Have you call jquery.min.js ?

Comment: no ,its imp to call jquery.min.js? i have added noe google cdn <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> above script tag $ defined error now gone bt output not coming

Comment: Yes it is...without js you can not use jquery..See below link...
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide

Comment: yes i did same not no error in code but output still not coming

Comment: yes!! it's working now :) thanks brother you helped me lot :)